# linux kernel_v_4.X slows down the TCP_UL throughput

Tags: linux

while running the iperf tcp_ul traffic on kernel version 4.X, i observed that , there is regression in the throughput of tcp_ul.
anyone know that , why this is happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the kernel version 4.4 onwards they modified the TCP congesion control algorithm, because of that TCP performance is degraded with multi-client environment.
you can check the latest kernel version.
kernel version 4.10.3 works for me well.
refer the kernel change log, so you comes to know that what they changed in the new version.